# String byte encoding issue

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

Given that I have following function

```
static void fun(String str) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s | length in String: %d | length in bytes: %d | bytes: %s", str, str.length(), str.getBytes().length, Arrays.toString(str.getBytes())));
    }
```

on invoking `fun("ó");` its output is

```
ó | length in String: 1 | length in bytes: 2 | bytes: [-61, -77]
```

so it means character ó needs 2 bytes to represent and as per Character class documentation too default is UTF-16 in java, considering that when I do following

```
System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));// output=쎳
System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));// output=Ã³
System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));// output=��
System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));// output=ó
System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE));// output=쎳
System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));// output=돃
```

Why any of UTF_16, UTF_16BE, UTF_16LE charset not able to decode bytes properly, given that bytes are representing a 16 bit length character?
And how UTF-8 is able decode it properly given that UTF-8 consider each character only 8 bit long so it should have printed 2 chars(1 char for each byte) like in ISO_8859_1.

Comment: What you do here does not make much sense. Building a string from a wrong encoding can only fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) always returns the bytes encoded in the platform's default charset, which is probably UTF-8 for you.

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

So you are essentially trying to decode a bunch of UTF-8 bytes with non-UTF-8 charsets. No wonder you don't get expected results.

Though kind of pointless, you can get what you want by passing the desired charset to `getBytes`, so that the string is encoded correctly.

```
    System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
    System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE), StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE));
    System.out.println(new String("ó".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
```

You also seem to have some misunderstanding about encodings. It's not *just* about the number of bytes that a character takes. The byte-count-per-character for two encodings being the same doesn't mean that they are compatible with each other. Also, it is not always one byte per character in UTF-8. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length encoding.